# Alamofire does not show all cookies

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, alamofire

I am using Alamofire http networking library in project. My goal is get all cookies from server after successful login. I write code as below but I am getting only one cookie.

```
let allCookies = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPCookieStorage?.cookiesForURL(NSURL(string: "my_domain.com")!)
```

[image: only one cookie]
Postman shows 4 cookies for same request. Why don't I get all 4 cookies with Alamofire ?

[image: all cookies]

Answer (score 0):

You get only your HTTP Cookie

In postman you can see you have only one http cookie.